# Check if app became active because of RemoteNotification ( App is already launched)

Tags: ios, swift, push

I want to differentiate if app becameActive in response to the RemoteNotification click. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check it like this

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
       NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
                if (notification) {

                // it's launch from notification


                }
                else
                {
                     // normal launch on app icon click
                }

    }
```

for swift plz use this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if (launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary) != nil {

           // it's launch from notification
                   }
        else
        {
              // normal launch on app icon click 
        }

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```